# Rails 3 Deploy: Multiple rails apps single domain error: No such file or directory - config/environment.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache

Yesterday, I bought a server on Linode. I setup Apache, RVM, Rails, MySQL and have got a single rails app hosted on a domain, following a nice guide from http://library.linode.com/frameworks/ruby-on-rails-apache/ubuntu-10.04-lucid. It also explains how to put multiple rails apps on the same domain, however when I try, I get an error when I access my domain our-portal.com/adm :

```
No such file or directory - config/environment.rb

Application root: /srv/www/our-portal.com/public_html
```

Somethings wrong here... anyone have any ideas? I am able to host a single app just fine, but not multiple... Here is my Virtual Host settings

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@our-portal.com
   ServerName  our-portal.com
   ServerAlias www.our-portal.com
   DocumentRoot /srv/www/our-portal.com/public_html/
   RailsBaseURI /adm
   RailsBaseURI /matrix
   ErrorLog  /srv/www/our-portal.com/logs/error.log
   CustomLog /srv/www/our-portal.com/logs/access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

My applications path is in /srv/www/our-portal.com/adm/ and I linked using

```
ln -s /srv/www/our-portal.com/adm/public/ /srv/www/our-portal.com/public_html/adm/
ln -s /srv/www/our-portal.com/matrix/public/ /srv/www/our-portal.com/public_html/matrix/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, these are the changes I made.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@our-portal.com
   ServerName  our-portal.com
   ServerAlias www.our-portal.com
   DocumentRoot /srv/www/our-portal.com/public_html
   <Directory /srv/www/our-portal.com/public_html>
         Allow from all
   </Directory>

   RailsBaseURI /adm
   RailsBaseURI /matrix
   <Directory /srv/www/our-portal.com/public_html/adm>
         Options -MultiViews
   </Directory>
   <Directory /srv/www/our-portal.com/public_html/matrix>
         Options -MultiViews
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog  /srv/www/our-portal.com/logs/error.log
   CustomLog /srv/www/our-portal.com/logs/access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

I also believe my links were not created correctly. It helped to type

```
ln -s
```

and double-click tab (without executing the command) to look at the correct way Unix handles the path for this function. My links looked like this

```
ln -s /srv/www/our-portal.com/adm/public/ our-portal.com/public_html/adm
ln -s /srv/www/our-portal.com/sitedb-pro/public/ our-portal.com/public_html/matrix
```

Notice the difference from my old links. Using double-click tab I was able to reference these folders correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting the `DocumentRoot` to the public folder of your application:

```
DocumentRoot /srv/www/our-portal.org/app/public
```

Comment: How can I host multiple apps on a single domain if I'm setting the DocumentRoot straight to a single app?

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, thanks though! I was looking for how to do it using RailsBaseURI under one VirtualHost.